# Get Click Listeners on Image coordinates

Tags: android, imageview, coordinates, pixel

I have an Imageview containing image of a location. The image has some areas which could be clicked eg. Consider a hospital, airport. Clicking on it I want to navigate user to next screen.The problem is to get separate click listeners of image portion and also I have functionality of zoom on image. Can anyone guide me how can i achieve that?

Comment: set the touch listener. It will give you touch coordinates, from which you can determine which part of image was clicked.

Comment: Does that provide same touch coordinates in all resolutions?

Comment: it provides touch coordinates on the view. It depends on how you've defined your ImageView.

Comment: Can u please explain more?

Comment: better just try it yourself

Comment: Does your different icons have different color in the imageview??

Comment: It has different color but those icons have gradient color combination.

Comment: @VladMatvienko well after many tries I have asked this on SO. I am expecting an answer not suggestion.

Comment: you can easily calculate the coordinates of the image from touch coordinates, ImageView dimensions and original image dimensions. if touched at x=50, original image width is 100 px, and ImageView width is 200 px, then original x coordinate will be 100 / 200 * 50 = 25. same for the y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:
It'll work best if your icons has different colors

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
        final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int x = (int)event.getX();
                int y = (int)event.getY();
```

now pixel will be having color code in int format according to which you can determine which icon is clicked

```
                    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
                    //if you want separate RGB value
                    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hi @sumit ..I want to get pixel color after zooming imageview. I tried your solution without zooming and its working but not in zoom case

Comment: @NancyY it shouldn't be happening. can you share how you're zooming your image??

Comment: See here i have posted my code too.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782121/get-color-of-bitmap-pixel-even-after-zoom

Answer (score 0):

Create various views that will overlap your images of hospital, airports, etc.
Set click listeners on those views to redirect the user to any screen you want.

This I think might be one of the solutions to your problem ..

Comment: In that case if i specify other view for instance a button at (50,50) coordinates, would it be same for all resolution device?