# Get Color of bitmap pixel even after zoom

Tags: android, zooming, pixel

I want to get the pixel color of Image on touch. I have managed to get the pixel color from my bitmap. But the problem here is **when i zoom that image,it returns white color everytime. I dont get the correct pixel value**. My exact requirement is to make image clickable. I have two images in a frame and second image will be invisible upon which I want to get the click color.My idea is to get the pixel of second image to further navigate in my application.

I am attaching my image which i want to click[image]

I am using zoomlayout code:

```
public class ZoomLayout extends FrameLayout implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

    private enum Mode {
        NONE,
        DRAG,
        ZOOM
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ZoomLayout";
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
    private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 16.0f;

    private Mode mode = Mode.NONE;
    private float scale = 1.0f;
    private float lastScaleFactor = 0f;

    // Where the finger first  touches the screen
    private float startX = 0f;
    private float startY = 0f;

    // How much to translate the canvas
    private float dx = 0f;
    private float dy = 0f;
    private float prevDx = 0f;
    private float prevDy = 0f;

    public ZoomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        final ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
        this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        float eventX = motionEvent.getX();
                        float eventY = motionEvent.getY();
                        float[] eventXY = new float[]{eventX, eventY};

                        Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
                        ((ImageView) getChildAt(1)).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

                        invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
                        int x = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
                        int y = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);


                        Log.e("image x", "===img ki x==" + x);
                        Log.e("image y", "===img ki y==" + y);

                        Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView) getChildAt(1)).getDrawable();
                        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();

                       // int color_value= getHitboxColour(x,y,(ImageView) getChildAt(0));

//Limit x, y range within bitmap
                        if (x < 0) {
                            x = 0;
                        } else if (x > bitmap.getWidth() - 1) {
                            x = bitmap.getWidth() - 1;
                        }

                        if (y < 0) {
                            y = 0;
                        } else if (y > bitmap.getHeight() - 1) {
                            y = bitmap.getHeight() - 1;
                        }


                        //Log.e("touched color: ", "" + "#" + Integer.toHexString(color_value));
                       int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

                        int redValue = Color.red(touchedRGB);
                        int blueValue = Color.blue(touchedRGB);
                        int greenValue = Color.green(touchedRGB);

                        Log.e("touched color: ", "" + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));


                        Log.i(TAG, "DOWN");
                        if (scale > MIN_ZOOM) {
                            mode = Mode.DRAG;
                            startX = motionEvent.getX() - prevDx;
                            startY = motionEvent.getY() - prevDy;
                        }



                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == Mode.DRAG) {
                            dx = motionEvent.getX() - startX;
                            dy = motionEvent.getY() - startY;

                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        mode = Mode.ZOOM;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = Mode.DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.i(TAG, "UP");
                        mode = Mode.NONE;
                        prevDx = dx;
                        prevDy = dy;
                        break;
                }
                scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

               /* if ((mode == Mode.DRAG && scale >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode == Mode.ZOOM) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
                    dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
                            + ", max " + maxDx);
                    applyScaleAndTranslation();

                }*/

                if (( scale >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode == Mode.ZOOM) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
                    dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
                            + ", max " + maxDx);
                   // applyScaleAndTranslation();
                    child().setScaleX(scale);
                    child().setScaleY(scale);

                    float maxDx1 = (child2().getWidth() - (child2().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    float maxDy1 = (child2().getHeight() - (child2().getHeight() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx1), maxDx1);
                    dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy1), maxDy1);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child2().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
                            + ", max " + maxDx1);
                    // applyScaleAndTranslation();
                    child2().setScaleX(scale);
                    child2().setScaleY(scale);


                }

                if(mode == Mode.DRAG ){
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
                    dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
                            + ", max " + maxDx);

                    child().setTranslationX(dx);
                    child().setTranslationY(dy);


                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    float maxDx1 = (child2().getWidth() - (child2().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    float maxDy1 = (child2().getHeight() - (child2().getHeight() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx1), maxDx1);
                    dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy1), maxDy1);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child2().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
                            + ", max " + maxDx);

                    child2().setTranslationX(dx);
                    child2().setTranslationY(dy);
                }



                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public int getHitboxColour(int x, int y,ImageView iv) {

       // ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_hitbox);

        Bitmap bmpHotspots;

        int pixel;



// Fix any offsets by the positioning of screen elements such as Activity titlebar.

// This part was causing me issues when I was testing out Bill Lahti's code.

        int[] location = new int[2];

        iv.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        x -= location[0];

        y -= location[1];



// Prevent crashes, return background noise

        if ((x < 0) || (y < 0)) {

            return Color.WHITE;

        }



// Draw the scaled bitmap into memory

        iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        bmpHotspots = Bitmap.createBitmap(iv.getDrawingCache());

        iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);



        pixel = bmpHotspots.getPixel(x, y);

        bmpHotspots.recycle();

        return pixel;

    }
    // ScaleGestureDetector

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onScaleBegin");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        float scaleFactor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.i(TAG, "onScale" + scaleFactor);
        if (lastScaleFactor == 0 || (Math.signum(scaleFactor) == Math.signum(lastScaleFactor))) {
            scale *= scaleFactor;
            scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));
            lastScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        } else {
            lastScaleFactor = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onScaleEnd");
    }

    private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
        child().setScaleX(scale);
        child().setScaleY(scale);
        child().setTranslationX(dx);
        child().setTranslationY(dy);




    }

    private View child() {
        return getChildAt(0);
    }


    private View child2() {
        return getChildAt(1);
    }


}
```

**XML file**

```
<com.diu.utils.ZoomLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/maplocation" />

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/maplocation"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</com.diu.utils.ZoomLayout>
```

Comment: show your code & did you tried anything to achieve that ?

Comment: I have added my code